# imagettftext() always gray even with black defined

Tags: php, imagettftext

A client of mine is trying to place text on a background image using imagettftext(). The code was working previously and suddenly went from displaying black text to displaying gray text. The code is properly set to black and changing it to any other color also has no effect.

```
$im     = imagecreatefrompng("/path/to/background.png");
$text = imagecolorallocate($im, 0, 0, 0);
imagettftext($im, 10, 0,96, 201,$text, "vera", $thiscardnumber);
imagepng($im, "/path/to/new/".$imagefilename.".png");
imagedestroy($im);
```

Any help would be appreciated as nothing was changed in the code or on the server that I am aware of to suddenly stop this from generating proper black text.

You can see the text generated here:

[image]

The black text is part of the background image, the gray text is generated by the code above.

Comment: I was able to somewhat recreate the same "black" text from your code, and find it quite strange that you're getting gray text instead. Have a look at the manual, it may help. I based myself in using example #1 http://www.php.net/imagettftext --- Plus, try using a different font; I used `monofont.ttf` --- Your font may have an opacity setting, who knows... stranger things have happened.

Comment: I tried using a different font, but I just get the light grey text in a different font =) I searched for any of the functions that had transparency settings listed in the docs for GD functions in PHP, but couldn't find any.

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT: From comments below**

Ah, OK. If you just recreate a the few lines of code separately, do you still get the grey text? Because I get black text with your code. What about if you try a different font, or a different base image just to eliminate them as the culprit? Have you verified what the value of $text is?

---

**ORIGINAL Answer:**

There's something amiss here. Your "x" and "y" coordinates are larger than the background image, so the text you are generating is off of the image canvas.

Is there any chance that your background image just has the grey text in it already, and the text you are generating is happening outside of the image?

[image]

Comment: That's what I was also thinking. The OP's `201` setting in `10, 0,96, 201` may be playing a role in all this. I changed it to `20` and it came out fine. Maybe it was a typo on someone's part.

Comment: Nope, that is not the issue, sadly. That would be an easy fix if it was =) The image I am using is much larger than the screenshot, I just used a small segment to illustrate the black background text next to the gray generated text. The text is being generated and appears properly in every way except the color. The data is submitted via a form, so I can see the text updating as different values are passed. It just is in that near unreadable grey color.

Comment: Ah, OK. If you just recreate a the few lines of code separately, do you still get the grey text? Because I get black text with your code. What about if you try a different font, or a different base image just to eliminate them as the culprit? Have you verified what the value of $text is?

Comment: The font I had already switched out, but the base image may be the issue! Creating a solid color file and switching it to that made my text appear black again. The image doesn't have any transparency in it so I am at a loss as to why it is causing this issue as well, but at least thats a good start! Thanks!